# numbers of users buying the exact same product from the same shop for > 2 times in 1 years

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have data like this:

```
date           user prod shop cat1 cat2
2022-02-01     1    a    a    ah   g
2022-02-02     1    a1   b    ah   g
2022-04-03     1    a    a    ah   g
2022-04-19     1    a    a    ah   g
2022-05-01     2    b    c    bg   g
```

I want to know how many user buy the same product in the same shop for >2 times in period 1 year. The result i want like:

```
table 1
cat1   number_of_user
ah     1

table 2
cat2   number_of_user
g      1
```

For total user, my query like:

```
WITH data_product AS(
SELECT DATE(payment_time) date,
user,
CONCAT(prod, "_", shop) product_shop,
cat1,
cat2
FROM
a
WHERE
DATE(payment_time) BETWEEN "2022-01-01" AND DATE_SUB(current_date, INTERVAL 1 day)
ORDER BY 1,2,3),
purchased AS (
SELECT user, product_shop, count(product_shop) tot_purchased
FROM data_product
GROUP BY 1,2
HAVING COUNT(product_shop) > 2
)
SELECT COUNT(user) number_of_user FROM purchased
```

Please help to get number of user buy the same product in the same shop more than 2 times in period based on `cat1` and `cat2`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this query might work. The first part shows count of customers who purchased same product *in category1* from same shop during one year. Second part shows that for *category2*, then we concatenate the two set by union operation :

```
with cte as
  (select distinct
    PDate,userID as userID,prod as prod,shop,cat1 as cat1,cat2,
    count(userID) over (partition by UserID,prod,shop,year(Pdate),cat1) as cat1_count,
    count(PDate) over (partition by UserID,prod,shop,year(Pdate),cat2) as cat2_count
 from tbl1)
select 
    cte.cat1 as c1,'0' as c2,count(distinct cte.cat1) as Num
 from cte
 where cte.cat1_count>1 
 group by cte.prod,cte.userID,cte.cat1
 union
 select 
    '0',cte.cat2,count(distinct cte.cat2)
 from cte
 where cte.cat2_count>1 
 group by cte.prod,cte.userID,cte.cat2
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
create temporary table table1 as(
select *,extract(YEAR from date) as year from `projectid.dataset.table`
);
 
create temporary table table2 as(
select * except(date,cat2) ,count(user) over(partition by cat1,year,user,prod,shop)  tcount  from table1
);
 
create temporary table table4 as(
select * except(date,cat1) ,count(user) over(partition by cat2,year,user,prod,shop)  tcount  from table1
);
 
select distinct year,cat1 ,count(distinct user) number_of_user from table2 where tcount>2 group by YEAR,cat1;
 
select distinct year,cat2 ,count(distinct user) number_of_user from table4 where tcount>2 group by YEAR,cat2;
```

If you want a single result set you can union both the select statements.